# Product of Lebesgue measure on Hilbert cube doesn't satisfy doubling condition?

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

The Hilbert cube $H$, is the infinite dimensional product $[0,1]\times [0,\frac12]\times...$ Let $\mu$ be product of Lebesgue measures $\mathcal{L}^1 \times \mathcal{L}^1\times...$, I heard that the measure doesn't satisfies the doubling property, i.e. there exists no $C$ s.t. $\mu(B_{2r}(x))\leqslant C\mu(B_{r}(x))$.

Question 1: Since $\mu(H)=1\times \frac12 \times \frac13...=0$, it's a measure?

Question 2: No ball contained in this cube, how can we say that the measure doesn't satisfy doubling property.

Or I misunderstand the measure induced on $H$?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: The product measure on the Hilbert cube is obtained as the product of *normalized* Lebesgue measures on the intervals $[0,1/k]$: that is, $\mathcal L^1$ is multiplied by $k$ to make the measure of $[0,1/k]$ equal to $1$.  This makes the product a probability measure.

Q2: When $X$ is a metric space and $Y\subset X$, the restriction of the metric gives a metric on $Y$. So, $Y$ is now also a metric space, so it has its own concept of open/closed balls. These are 
$$ \{y\in Y : d(y,y_0) < r\}\quad \text{and}\quad \{y\in Y : d(y,y_0) \le r\} $$ 
So, every subset of a metric space contains open and closed balls, if they are understood with respect to that subspace. (Alternatively, one can refer to the balls of the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ itself, since $\mu$ is also a measure on  $\ell^2$.)

**Proof that $\mu$ is not doubling**. Consider the ball  (in the sense of $H$) of radius $1/n$ around the origin $(0,0,\dots)$. This ball is contained in the product 
$$[0,1/n]\times [0,1/n]\times \cdots \times [0,1/n] \times [0,1/(n+1)]\times \cdots$$
so its measure is at most 
$$\frac1n \times \frac2n \times \cdots\times \frac{n}{n} \times 1 \times\cdots = \frac{n!}{n^n}<\frac{1}{e^n}$$
(using Stirling's formula).

Let $n=2^j$ here. If the doubling condition holds, then the measure of the ball of radius $1/2^j$ has to be at least $1/C^{j+1}$ (apply the doubling property $j+1$ times and observe that the ball of radius $2$ around $0$ is all of $H$). But the above estimate shows it's less than $\exp(-2^j)$, which is super-exponential decay.